# jquery animation doesn't work properly on first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is the code: [code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axf3zr5s/). On the first run it doesn't show the "slideDown" animation but subsequent times it works fine.

```
$("#more-news") .click(function() {
   $(".news-hide") .slideDown('slow').removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: Not to answer your question, but jQuery has `slideToggle` - so you could remove some of the duplicated code - http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following.

```
$("#more-news").click(function() {
    //changed the line below.
    $(".news-hide").hide().removeClass('hide').slideDown('slow');
    $("#less-news").fadeIn('slow').removeClass("hide");
    $("#more-news").fadeOut().addClass("hide");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/axf3zr5s/7/)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using multiple elements and multiple events, you can use like this,

```
$("#more-news").click(function() {
  var button = $(this)
  $(".news-hide").slideToggle(function() {
    $(".news-hide").is(":visible") ? button.text("Less News") : button.text("More News")
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/axf3zr5s/12/)

Comment: OP has the opposite scenario. At first the new is hidden.

Comment: It is not a big deal, OP can adjust the code.see the updated fiddle.

Comment: What OP Stands for ?

Comment: @Microsmsm see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap hide class doesn't quite work the same way as the jQuery hide function, creating a confusing result.

To jQuerify your hidden things before sliding them around, you can do something a little like this:

```
$('.hide').hide().removeClass('hide');

$("#more-news") .click(function() {
    $(".news-hide") .slideDown('slow');
});
```

Now you don't have to worry about that hide class every time you do something, but it keeps things hidden until the document is ready to javascript itself.